# How to turn off display but not lock the screen in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: display-settings, lock, windows-server-2012

For various reasons I want my server to:

- Automatically turn off the display after 10 minutes of inactivity.
- Never go into sleep mode.
- Never lock the screen automatically.

So, if I were to leave my server now, in 10 minutes the displays would power down (since Windows turns off the displays). And as soon as I touched the keyboard or mouse it would be just where I left it (without me having to enter Ctrl+Alt+Delete, password or anything).

How can I do this? I have it working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (without any 3rd party tools), but I can't get it to work in Windows Server 2012 R2.

The server(s) are part of a domain. and they are both running Hyper-V. I don't think I have any GPO that affects this.
In the Power Setting there is an option to turn off the display after a certain amount of time - that works. However, it locks the screen at the same time (which I see when I move the mouse when the screen goes black).

The screen saver is set to none. I want to be able to manually lock the screen (with Win+L).

Comment: Try this: [How to disable Windows Server 2012 auto lock feature](http://www.ittrainingday.com/2014/01/how-to-disable-windows-server-2012-auto.html).

Comment: I think it was already answered on ServerFault: [Windows Server 2012 R2 prevent automatic logoff due to inactivity](http://serverfault.com/questions/546225/windows-server-2012-r2-prevent-automatic-logoff-due-to-inactivity)

Answer (score 0):

MS is funny. Set your display in the power config to turn off "never". If your server is a domain member, you should set the GP "Do not display the lock screen" for this machine also. That's it.

Of course I advise against this practice ;)

Comment: But if I set the display to turn off "never", then the screens won't ever turn off, and then the physical display won't go into power save. (which is bad since I notoriously forget to turn them off)